# @font-face - embedded fonts not loading

Tags: css, fonts, embed

I can't seem to get @font-face to pull down these embedded fonts.

Page is here: http://clubs.speareducation.com/resources/

The header "Download Digital Resources" is suppose to be gotham_htfregular.

Take a look at my global.css stylesheet (fonts are at the top).  Have tried double quotes, single quotes... I have never had trouble with this before... Am I missing something here?

Here is my CSS.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "gotham_htfregular";
src: url("gothahtfregular-webfont-webfont.eot");
src: url("gothahtfregular-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("gothahtfregular-webfont-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
     url("gothahtfregular-webfont-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("gothahtfregular-webfont-webfont.svg#gotham_htfregular") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The font files are not rendering properly for me in Chrome's Inspector. They may be corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The URLs of the font files are not properly set. Check them out.

Comment: You were correct with the URL part.  Turned out to be someone had set rewrite condition in my .htaccess file, adding this  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources fixed my problem.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: So, go ahead! select this as the answer :) also, i would suggest, you use a seperate fonts.css file and keep all the font files in the same directory so that the css can find the files easily.

Answer (score 0):

I see gothahtfbol-webfont-webfont, gothahtfboo-webfont-webfont, and gothahtfmed-webfont-webfont, all loaded as 'gotham_htfregular'; so tell me, which of these files you're importing contains 'gotham_htfregular'? looks like there's bold, medium, and something else, but none of them look like they're regular.

Comment: Turned out to be someone had set rewrite condition in my .htaccess file, adding this  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources fixed my problem.  Thank you for the help.